# How to add Reference line for Counting Object on Conveyor using opencv Python tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to build a vision system that can count chocolates moving on a variable speed conveyor belt. Using OpenCV and python. Similar to this:
[image]

I tried many solutions provided in the Stackoverflow, but none of them were helpful. Regarding this, I am requesting help from experts in this community for implementing help in the below code.

Somehow, I manage to create a Tkinter GUI with the help of cv2.VideoCapture.

The code I have attached only has the Tkinter window to show video feed. I want to add code so that it shows a reference line in the video frame as shown in the image attached below.

**Help required section:** 
1. I wanted to implement a reference line for the video frame so that when the object crosses the line it counts the object.

2. How I could separate the blobs and extract the respective centroids.
3. I have to increment the count variable if the centroid crosses the Reference boundary line.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk  import Frame
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

white       = "#ffffff"
lightBlue2  = "#adc5ed"
font        = "Constantia"
fontButtons = (font, 12)
maxWidth    = 800
maxHeight   = 480

#Graphics window
mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.configure(bg=lightBlue2)
mainWindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (maxWidth,maxHeight,0,0))
mainWindow.resizable(0,0)
# mainWindow.overrideredirect(1)

mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.place(x=20, y=20)

#Capture video frames
lmain = tk.Label(mainFrame)
lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def show_frame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2image   = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

    img   = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((760, 400))
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, show_frame)

closeButton = Button(mainWindow, text = "CLOSE", font = fontButtons, bg = white, width = 20, height= 1)
closeButton.configure(command= lambda: mainWindow.destroy())
closeButton.place(x=270,y=430)

show_frame()  #Display
mainWindow.mainloop()  #Starts GUI
```

**Expected GUI**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Gil for your efforts. It was very helpful.

After searching on google I came across the answer that satisfies my requirements. I will be very thankful for experts of this community if they help me in **implementing the following logic in Tkinter window** with the following buttons/trackbars/entry widgets (any of these will work):

1. Snapshot
2. Close
3. lineypos
4. lineypos2
5. minarea
6. maxarea

currently, I am entering this value in my script. But I need help in implementing these logics in Tkinter so that I can manipulate these values manually. So to seek help, I have to post the next question. I have provided the solution in the **code section** of the below link. 
[How to create a tkinter window & attach tkinter control button for a OpenCV video frame to manipulate values manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629607/how-to-create-a-tkinter-window-attach-tkinter-control-button-for-a-opencv-vide)

Answer (score 0):

so far, your code is only able to capture a video (the ''ret, frame = cap.read()'' ) and display it through a GUI (build by Tkinter).

Your next steps would be to :
-draw a line in your screen (use cv2.line fonction with a set of x,y coordinates).

-process the image to remove un-needed informations and then  detect shape/contours on the image to segment the rectangle chocolate.

-to detect the centroid, you could try cv2.moments or calculate it manually if you know the rectangle dimensions.

-to count the object when they passed the line,I would just use a if statement with the x/y pixel position of the object:

let's assume your conveyor moves the object from right to left

```
if object_position_x < detected_line_position:
    counter = counter+1
    print (counter)
else:
   print (counter)
```

If you are just looking to draw vertical line, use this code

```
import cv2

def viewImage(image):
    cv2.namedWindow('Display', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('Display', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


image = cv2.imread('myimage.JPG')

#the 2 lines below are using the image.shape attributes to automatically calculate the dimension of the image
#basically it says : startpoint = middle column of the image, line 0
#                    endpoint = middle column of the image, last row
start_point = ((int(image.shape[1]/2)), 0) 
end_point = ( (int(image.shape[1]/2)), (int(image.shape[0])) )
color = (0, 0, 255)
thickness = 2

cv2.line(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)
viewImage(image)
```

hope it helps